# Why does this code work for any of the alphabets that have an index over 16?

Tags: python

I can't understand why this code will work for any letter after "p" , but it does because we used the `%`.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
punctuation = ".,?'! "
message = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"

translated_message = ""

for letter in message:
    if not letter in punctuation:
        letter_value = alphabet.find(letter)
        translated_message += alphabet[(letter_value + 10) % 26]
    else:
        translated_message += letter
print(translated_message)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [modulo operator `%`](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/) in Python

Answer (score 1):

Any letter index greater than 15 will produce a corresponding index (+10) that is greater or equal to 26.  The modulo operator (`%`) will bring back those index below 26 (essentially wrapping around within the 26 letters).

Modulo is the remainder of an integer division.  So, for example if the original letter is at index 19, then you will be dividing 29 by 26 which gives a quotient of 1 and a remainder of 3.  This will give you alphabet[3] as the corresponding letter_value < 0 instead.

In short, any number modulo 26 will produce a value smaller than 26 and greater than zero (which is within the range of indexation of alphabet)

Note that the program doesn't need to check for punctuation, the .find() function will return -1 if it doesn't find a letter in alphabet so you can check for letter_value >= 0 to perform the translation.

Also, given that your offset is less than 26, you could simply double the alphabet string and avoid using modulo altogether:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" * 2   # allow indexes > 26
for letter in message:
    letter_value = alphabet.find(letter)      # will find 1st occurrence
    if letter_value >= 0:                     # if it is in alphabet
        letter = alphabet[letter_value + 10]  # then translate it
    translated_message += letter              # assemble result
```

If later on you want to reverse the translation you can reverse the alphabet and use the rest of the code as is

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" * 2   # allow indexes > 26

if decoding: alphabet = alphabet[::-1]        # reverse alphabet to decode

for letter in message:
    letter_value = alphabet.find(letter)      # will find 1st occurrence
    if letter_value >= 0:                     # if it is in alphabet
        letter = alphabet[letter_value + 10]  # then translate it
    translated_message += letter              # assemble result
```

Comment: Or you could subtract 16 instead of adding 10.

Comment: Indeed, subtracting 16 instead of adding 10 leverages Python's support for negative indexes so doubling the alphabet wouldn't be needed.   Then decoding could be performed by subtracting 10 instead of reversing the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

The Caesar Cipher is a really nice cipher. It works out that the first 15 letters are equal to that `letter_position + 10`. But I totally understand your confusion when using the `%` sign.

But let me explain some maths:

For the first 15 letters, the corresponding letter is its position in the alphabet, plus ten spots. Let's use the letter `i` as an example.

```
#'i' is the 8th letter of the alphabet
letter = 'i'
pos = 8

translated_pos = pos + 10
#translated_pos = 18
```

This is where the `%` comes in.
Although putting this into a calculator you would find the resulting devision `18 / 26` to result a small number, smaller than 1.

This is where one of the rules of Modulo is used:

```
Let *a mod b*
Where *b > a > 0* then *a mod b = a*
```

This means that for all numbers smaller than 16 (to be smaller than 26 when 10 is added) it is the same position in the alphabet.

Now for any letter in the code after `p`:
The Modulo calculation is in fact very simple.

Let's use the letter `w` as an example.

```
#'w' is the 22nd letter of the alphabet.
letter = 'w'
pos = 22

translated_pos = pos + 10
#translated_pos = 32
```

To find the mod 26 of 32 you take away 26 from 32 until the resulting number would be less than 0 (equal to zero is fine). How much is left is the answer to your modulo equation.

```
start = 32
step = 26

32 - 26 = 6
6 - 26 = -20 #Too far

#This gives the corresponding letter of 22 (w) to 6 (g) the remainder of the first equation
```

I made a quick dictionary using python if you wanted to write your own message easier.

```py
alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


for letter in message:
    letter_value = alphabet.find(letter)
    print(letter_value, letter, (letter_value+10) % 26, alphabet[(letter_value + 10) % 26])
```

Comment: thank you so much Alain T.,PotSkill, nw i understand